# Creating Multiple windows of same NSWindowController class type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I want to create a NSWindow of same NSWindowController class type each time user sends an action.

This is my Code.

```
objController = [[MyController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyController"];
[objController showWindow:nil];
```

This is a simple two liner which gives me NSWindow. but the thing is, If I don't make a class level object, the window doesn't get displayed. So, I had to make a class level object. It worked well and gave me NSWindow of type MyController.

But, since it is a class level object, If I want to trigger this action every time user clicks on a button, previous window gets closed. And new window gets appeared.

I don't want this to happen. I want to keep all the previous NSWindows in memory and user can interact with them.

How do I do it ?

I think, this should be something small but at the time I don;t have any solution in my hand.

Kindly help me to get this.

Thank you.

Comment: Just wondering, what do you mean by "class level object"? How are you storing `objController` in the code snippet above?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that by "class level object" you mean a `@property` of type `MyController`, which can indeed only hold a single window controller. If you need to store several instances of `MyController` and do not want to create a separate `@property` for each of them, you need to put them into an array type, namely a `NSMutableArray`.

Add a `@property NSMutableArray *myControllers` to your class and initialize the array (for example in the `- init` method or your class) with `self.myControllers = [NSMutableArray array]`.
Now you can add newly created window controllers to it with `[self.myControllers addObject:]` which makes them stay in memory instead of overwriting each other by sharing the same property for storage.

Comment: That is true, Elwisz. We can do this. I have used this approach in my project already. I thought that, there should be a straight way to get the functionality. 
Adding the controller's object to an array so that the object will stay in memory and once user closes it down we can remove it from an array as well. I have done this.

But, is there any other straight way to achieve what I asked for ?

Comment: This is about as straight as it can get! Your key problem is that you need to store references to several controller instances in order to prevent them from vanishing. You have two options: create a separate property for each controller or a single property that is an array storing the controllers.